# Quantitatively writing spring mass equation in accelerating and non -accelerating frames

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I have two questions, the second one is related to the first one.

1.The first question is about direction of acceleration in SHM. Now, we all know that the acceleration in SHM is directed towards center of oscillation. My point is about writing the equation correctly.

Say I have a spring mass system in the vertical direction and I taken +direction of X as V-Up.

Then the equation of motion is , considering the equation written from an inertial system

Kxst +kx- mg = -mx (double dot) from which cancelling Kxst ( xst being the static displacement from the equilibrium length of the spring) and mg we write mx(double dot)= -kx

My first question is, as the above is a vector equation, and we know that the acceleration will be upward ( the mass is given an initial displacement in downward direction ie. -X direction) , why we write -mx (double dot) as that indicates a downward acceleration?

2. The second question is about the same spring mass system in an elevator which is going upwards at an uniform acceleration and its effect on time period of the resulting SHM. I am writing the equation in both inertial frame (ground) and non-inertial frame ( the frame of the accelerating elevator).

In the ground frame, again with X taken as + upwards,

Kxst +Kx-mg = m x acceleration of the mass in ground frame. If the spring is given an initial displacement (downward) in the lift, then the acceleration should be in +X direction, but as with the previous example, if we write this value ( x double dot ) as in -X direction, then 
Kx= -mx (double dot) showing that acceleration of the lift doesn't change the basic equation. However this presumes like the previous proble, x double dot be written in -X direction to get the differential equation of SHM.

In the accelerating frame of the elevator 
Kxst +Kx-mg - ma ( where a is the upward uniform acceleration of the lift in the inertial frame of ground and hence the pseudo force is in -X direction) = m x acceleration of the mass in the non inertial frame of the elevator).
Now acceleration of mass in elevator frame= acceleration of mass in ground frame ( taken as -x double dot in-X direction,) + acceleration of ground in elevator frame ( -a , as the elevator is accelerating upwards)
 Hence acceleration of mass in elevator frame = -x double dot -a = -(x double dot+a) 
hence the equation of motion is 
Kxst +Kx-mg-ma = -m(x double dot +a) 
 i.e. kx -ma= -mx double dot -ma 
Giving again kx= -mx double dott.

I am sure I am making some mistake both with the sign of acceleration as well as the form of the equation in non -inertial frame as , in non inertial frame the form of SHM equation , as far as I am aware is different from that in an inertial frame.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

How to get the equation of motion.

**1)** choose arbitrary positive x direction

the inertia force include the g force  is always opposite to the x direction .

**2)** "do" a free body diagram and take the sum of the forces equal zero.

Thus:

**Model I)**

$$m\,\ddot{x}+m\,g-F_s=0$$

to get harmonic wave the spring force must be $F_s=-k\,x-k\,l_0$

**Model II)**

$$m\,\ddot{x}+m\,g+F_s=0$$

to get harmonic wave the spring force must be $F_s=+k\,x-k\,l_0$

in both case you get the same equation of motion, as it should be